# add image in listview with tabhost

Tags: android, listview, android-tabhost

This is the .xml of the MainActivity, It's composed by two tabhost, the first contain a dynamic listview.
I want to add in the beginning of every item of listview an image like an icon or logo.

What are modifications of the .xml that i must do.
thx

this is main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp">

        <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: listview created in java code or list view items set dynamically (changes are done to it dynamically) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a tutorial of using Custom ArrayAdapter with ListView: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429.
Here is another tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up an adapter for your `ListView` and then in the `getView` of the adapter inflate or programmatically create a group of views that represents each individual item in the `ListView`.

You should *google* tutorials about how to set up adapters for `ListView`s